# how many two-digit number ab that satisfy: ab = a² + b² + 1

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out the above but I have come to a blank , this is what i have so far, this is the only information I was given for question in the title, I can not explain any further

```
# Challenge 4
n = int(input("N="))
# count how many two-digit number ab satisfy the equation
count = 0
for i in range( n ):
    ab = int(input("Enter a two digit number:"))
    def get_digit(number, ab):
        return number // 10 ** ab % 10
    a = get_digit(ab, 0)
    b = get_digit(ab, 1)
    if ab == (a ** 2) + (b ** 2) + 1:
        count = count + 1
print( "Number of two-digit number ab that satisfy the equation=", count )
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to be able to test whether for example 34 = 3² + 4² + 1, right? Looks like you're using human input to deliver your values for testing - how is that working out? - where is your actual problem?

Comment: Not sure what is the question here... You present us with some code - is it not working? Giving you wrong results? Are you looking for improvements? The latter should be done in [codereview.se]

Comment: Your code works for me. There are two numbers matching that condition: 35 and 75. What result do you get?

Comment: The title is all I was given from my university in terms of solving it, yeah the answer is 2

Comment: @Xdh this site is for "coders helping coders". You present us with a code that supposed to solve a certain problem and say if it has an error or doesn't produce the output you expected and we will try to help. Currently your question is presenting a code that seems to work just fine, so saying *I have come to a blank* is both off-topic here and confusing. You need to be more specific when asking a question. How is the current output different from what you expect? If you don't understand the requirements of an exercise - this is not the address, your teacher is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a nested for loop where `a` and `b` are digits of the two-digit number `a * 10 + b` which ranges from `0` to `99`.

```
count = 0
for a in range(1, 10):
    for b in range(0, 10):
        if a * 10 + b == a ** 2 + b ** 2 + 1:
            print(a * 10 + b, ' ')
            count += 1
print("\nNumber of two-digit number ab that satisfy the equation =", count)
```

Output:

```
35 75
Number of two-digit number ab that satisfy the equation = 2
```

Or alternatively by using a list comprehension you can pack those numbers in a list and then print.

```
out = [a * 10 + b for a in range(1, 10) for b in range (0, 10) if a * 10 + b == a ** 2 + b ** 2 + 1]
print(out)
print('Number of two-digit number ab that satisfy the equation =', len(out))
```

Output:

```
[35, 75]
Number of two-digit number ab that satisfy the equation = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate all two digit numbers by using `range(10, 100)` which will include 10...99. For any two digit number you can use integer division `//10` to get the 10's digit, and modulus `%10` to get the 1's digit.

```
for ab in range(10, 100):
    a = ab // 10
    b = ab % 10
    if ab == a**2 + b**2 + 1:
        print(ab)
```

Output

```
35
75
```

As a more concise list comprehension

```
>>> [ab for ab in range(10, 100) if ab == (ab//10)**2 + (ab%10)**2 + 1]
[35, 75]
```

And then obviously if you want the count you can just take the `len` of that list

```
>>> results = [ab for ab in range(10, 100) if ab == (ab//10)**2 + (ab%10)**2 + 1]
>>> len(results)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
flag = 0
for val in range(10,100):
   if val == (val // 10) ** 2 + (val % 10) ** 2 + 1:
      flag += 1
print("Answer", flag)
```